# Kartik's star-rating: how to put pluginevents?

Tags: yii2

I made the next:

1. Installed Kartik's star-rating widget in my Yii2 aplication
2. Maked settings for 'pluginOptions'
3. Till now all it's working, but i don't now how to work with
   'pluginevents'. For the start i want to make a simple alert('ok')
   for the "rating-chage" event, but without succes:

Code:

```
  echo StarRating::widget([
       'name' => $post->post_rate,
       'value' => isset($post->post_rate) ? $post->post_rate : 0,
       'pluginOptions' => [
                     'size'=>'xs',
                     'filledStar' => '&#x2605;',
                     'emptyStar' => '&#x2606;', 
                     'showCaption' => false,
                     ],
       'pluginEvents' => [
                    "rating.change" => "function() \n\t{\n\t alert('ok'); \n\t}\n\t"
                     ],
```

**Question**:
Why not working alert after that i cliked on a star?

[Image from view:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2E9g.png)

Comment: posted an answer see if that helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is common mistake that is done when you try to use this plugin for the first time it should be `rating:change` rather than `rating.change` if you look into `javascript` [documentation](http://plugins.krajee.com/star-rating-demo-advanced-usage) change it to the following

```
echo StarRating::widget([
      'name' => $post - > post_rate,
      'value' => isset($post - > post_rate) ? $post - > post_rate : 0,
      'pluginOptions' => [
        'size' => 'xs',
        'filledStar' => '&#x2605;',
        'emptyStar' => '&#x2606;',
        'showCaption' => false,
      ],
      'pluginEvents' => [
        "rating:change" => "function() { alert('ok'); }"
      ],
```

Comment: you are welcome @futur1st , glad i could help, please do select the answer as correct if it works for you